# How to manipulate LatLng objects?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am running a request towards a database and gets (as shown with JSON.Stringify() in the console:

```
sites : [{"siteName":"Site de Marseille",
"siteAdress1":"rue du string",
"siteAddress2":"string",
"siteCodPost":"13010","siteTown":"Marseille",
"id":"5d0ce7c4a06b07213a87a753",
"companyId":"5cd430745304a21b9464a219",
"customerId":"5cd430c65304a21b9464a21a",
"points":
[
 {"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},
 {"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},    
 {"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}]}
]
```

This is a record with some properties and one property is an array of Lat/Lng.
To get this record I have the following code:

```
 this.customerApi.getSites(this.currentUser.id)
.subscribe(response => {
  this.sites = response;
  console.log('sites : ' + JSON.stringify(this.sites));
});
  }
```

I am getting an Observable() that I show in the console.

I would like to get the Point property and push it to an array of arrays as it could exist many records sent back by the back-end.
The goal is to have nested coordinates that could draw polygons on Google Map with Angular Google Map angular component

For this, I have declared:

```
rectangles: Array<Array<LatLngLiteral>> = [];
```

and under the "subscribe" do a:

```
.subscribe(response => {
  this.sites = response;
  this.rectangles.push(this.sites.points);
```

rectangles is empty.

Any idea that could help me a lot please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your datastructure that sites is an array. So if you do `this.sites.points` it will be `undefined`.

What you want is: `this.rectangles.push(this.sites.map(s => s.points))`

The difference is you tried to access the property `sites` on an array.
Arrays don't have that property, consequently it is undefined. Arrays are build in data structures with a defined set of functions and properties like `length` or `map`

For example:

```
const exampleObject = {propertyA: "value", propertyB: "another value" }

//access properties on object

//"value"
exampleObject.propertyA

//"another value"
exampleObject.propertyB

const exampleArray = ["one", "two", "three"]

//propertyA does not exists = undefined
exampleArray.propertyA

//lenght property exists on all arrays = 3
exampleArray.length
```

Arrays do have a function called `map` this means call a function on every element and return a new array. It is commonly used to transform data structures or to get a deeper nested element.

This is just shorthand:

```
this.sites.map(s => s.points)
```

Actually it means this:

```
const pointsArray = this.sites.map(s => {
       //s is a single element in sites array
       // s has property points which is an array
       return s.points
    })


// now we have an array of points, we can add it to rectangles

this.reactangles.push(pointsArray)
```

Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: rectangles is populated but still facing types issue: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidValueError: at index 0: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
Error

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This means the lat value is not correctly typed. Maybe it is maybe string instead of a number. Try to create it this way: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)

Comment: It comes from a database and is retrieved through an Observable(). I think yes it is a string instead of a number but if I do this.rectangles.push(this.sites.map(s => s.points)); I do not manipulate it at all. Somewhere I need to use parseFloat. Somewhere ...

Comment: also rectangles has 3 quare brackets: rectangles : [[[{"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},{"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},{"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}],[{"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},{"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}]]]. It is declared as rectangles: Array<Array<LatLngLiteral>> = [];